# SwiftUI Toggle changing state when entering background

Tags: swiftui

I have a view with a list and inside the list there is a toggle that is binded with a boolean in the viewmodel, if I turn on the toggle the boolean is true and viceversa, the issue here is that if I turn on the toggle, and then enter background when I reopen the app, the toggle appears turned off even when the boolean is true, then I go back to the previous screen and when I return to the screen with the toggle it appears turned on, is there a way to avoid this issue? here is the List code below:

```
List {
        Section(header: Text("Flags")) {
            ForEach(viewModel.flags.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Toggle(isOn: $viewModel.flags[index].isActive) {
                    Text(viewModel.flags[index].name.rawValue.camelCaseToCapitalized())
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is very weird that the app would lose its state when going to background. The provided code would not cause that on its own, but some other parts of your app.

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the onAppear modifier to update the state of the toggle when the view appears.

```
List {
        Section(header: Text("Flags")) {
            ForEach(viewModel.flags.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                Toggle(isOn: $viewModel.flags[index].isActive) {
                    Text(viewModel.flags[index].name.rawValue.camelCaseToCapitalized())
                }
                .onAppear {
                    viewModel.flags[index].isActive = true
                }
            }
        }
```